# Execute file compiled by sbcl cannot make random or make with-open-file work

Tags: random, lisp, common-lisp, sbcl, slime

I write a script with using random and with-open-file, it works well in slime by emacs. But it cannot work when I use sbcl compile it to a execute file.

My purpose is using this code to choice the random video to open.`;update at 1/1/2016`

Code:`;update at 1/1/2016`

```
(setf *random-state* (make-random-state t))
(defun choice-file-to-open (files) ;file is a list content all pathspecs which I want to open
  (let ((filePath (nth (random (length files)) files)))
    (open-by-system filePath) ;use shell command "open" to open file
    (with-open-file (file "./logs" :direction :output
                          :if-exists :append
                          :external-format '(:utf-8 :replacement #\?))
      (format file "~S~%" (namestring filePath))) ;write filename in log file to record the open history
      ))
```

`open-by-system` is a function to open file.

My purpose is pick random file in the folder. But it always choice the same file to open when I use it. **Only for the singer execute file compiled by sbcl, the slime during emacs work well**.

Then I add the log file to record the filename every time I open. But there is no log file, as same as problem before, this problem only issues in executed file, and code works well in slime. **with-open-file** won't work in singer execute file compiled, but slime work well.

I found the answer [(Random) in Common Lisp Not So Random?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4034042/random-in-common-lisp-not-so-random) and it cannot solve the random problem.

What wrong with me? There are many differences between slime and sbcl?

Comment: without seeing the rest of the code and how it is called from the command line, this is not possible to debug...

Comment: `With-open-file` already opens the file.  What do you need `open-by-system` for?

Comment: Are you sure you initialise the internal random state? If not, it's probably starting from the same state every time you run the program.

Comment: I already add `(setf *random-state* (make-random-state t))` at the beginning of codes, but it doesn't work. `open-by-system` is open the file by shell `open` command, I used with-open-file to make a log file.

Comment: Please update your code so that we can see the whole script and try to reproduce your problem.

Comment: You probably mean `;update at 1/1/2016`

Comment: thank you guys, I fix them.

Answer (score 1):

I fix them by myself. There are two problems in my old codes. Firstly, random not work well. Secondly, the `with-open-file` don't work.

The codes worked below:

```
(defun choice-file-to-open (files) ;file is a list content all pathspecs which I want to open
  (let ((filePath (nth (random (length files) (make-random-state t)) files)))
    (open-by-system filePath) ;use shell command "open" to open file
    (with-open-file (file "./logs" 
                          :direction :output
                          :if-does-not-exist :create
                          :if-exists :append
                          :external-format '(:utf-8 :replacement #\?))
      (format file "~S~%" (namestring filePath))) ;write filename in log file to record the open history
      ))
```

`(make-random-state t)` should be added at the end of `random`. Then fix the random problem.

`:if-does-not-exist :create` should be add because the log file don't existed. Then fix the log file can't create problem.